# Session variable fails, php issue

Tags: php, forms, session

```
session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

This is how I start my code.

I , then, pass taht $token variable to a hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

but that condition is never true:

```
if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
{       
        echo 'Session was valid<br/>';
}
```

why?

Comment: What is in `$_POST['token']` and `$_SESSION['token']` when you do the comparison if not the right value?

Comment: the hidden field is called post,,and also the session variable is called token and a php variable is called token. $token, should be the same inside all of them

Comment: maybe because you generate `$token` every time page loads/reloads and it's being changed before your form data being validated?

Comment: Have you tried to echo out the tokens to see if they actually contain corresponding values? (echo $_POST['token']; echo $_SESSION['token'];)

Comment: I applied that approach and the code that AVD has provided, it works now..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page submit, a new value will be assigned to the session.

Try,

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
 $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
 $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}
```

Comment: yup, it has fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Because you regenerate your token BEFORE checking it. You have to change it AFTER you're sure it's not the same

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing `$_SESSION['token']` into the form instead of `$token`, in case you accidentally re-assigned it between the creation of the token and the form output.

I once had a problem very similar to this when I was developing something that took me ages to find, and it turned out that it was because I had left an `<img src=''>` in, because I didn't yet have the image - this caused the page to be requested again, since an empty `src` means 'this page', so the token was re-generated after the page was loaded.

Another thing to check is if the form's `action` attribute is missing, or some value that points to itself, the token maybe regenerated when the form is submitted, before the `if (...)` statement.

Comment: very helpful. I havent thought about it.. I do think the form regenerates itself

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in order to prevent resetting the token on every page load:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}
```

But... you may be better off [session.referer_check](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.referer-check) or using some open source Session class that incorporates finer grained security than tacking this on top of the procedural standard. (if done correctly your code won't have to change wherever you actually use the session.) 
see [php.net/session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the Code you provide is in one file and you submitting it to itself.
that regenerate the token and assign to the session variable. As said by "AVD" is the code to prevent the reassigning it

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['token'])){
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}
```

then you can compare your condition where you are going to check.